# External use of Ansible templating engine

Tags: python, templates, ansible, jinja2, templating

I want to use `ansible` excellent templating engine (based on `Jinja2`) in another project, that use template variables.

The template variables can make use of all `ansible` lookups and filters.

I'd like to establish a pipeline for rendering similar to this:

`input.yaml.j2` => `ansible (template engine)` => `output.yaml`

**Example:**

**`input.yaml.j2`**

```
vars:
  users: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/users.json') }}"

template:
  - name: "{{ item.name }}"
    type: "user"
    fist_user_group: "{{ item.user_groups.0 }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ users }}"
```

**`/tmp/users.json`**

```
[
  {'John': 'groups': ['apache', 'webapp']},
  {'Rohit': 'groups': ['rabbitmq', 'postgresql']}
]
```

**`output.yaml`**

```
- name: "John"
  type: "user"
  first_user_group: "apache"

- name: "Rohit"
  type: "user"
  first_user_group: "rabbitmq"
```

**Question:**

How can I use `ansible` rendering engine to parse my own templates ?

Comment: Why not use tiny playbook that executes `template` module?

Comment: That might just work fine. Could you please give an example ? I'm not very familiar with `ansible` but was impressed by the rendering feature. How would I do run this playbook locally from Python code ? Is there a way I can get the output templates in memory instead of files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: input.j2
        dest: output.file
```

Execution: `ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml`.

For you information Ansible uses slightly extended version of [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/) template engine.
Take a look at it – this can be the thing you actually want.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. It's working pretty well. I'd hoped we could just call the module that's responsible for rendering, directly from Python. (faster), instead of loading the whole Ansible factory using `ansible` CLI.

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but I do something slightly different in some of my `Makefiles`, Instead of relying on a playbook I just use Ansible in ad-hoc mode: `ansible localhost -m template -a 'src=input.j2 dest=output.file`. This makes it easy to substitute Makefile variables like `$<` or `$@` into the task.

Answer (score 0):

Running the Ansible [`template`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#template-module) module as an [ad-hoc command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/command_guide/intro_adhoc.html#intro-adhoc) works well for simple uses:

```
# hide: [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
export ANSIBLE_LOCALHOST_WARNING=False
export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_UNPARSED_WARNING=False

# put the jinja2 template string you want to evaluate in a file
echo '{{"test template"|split(" ")}} {{somekey}}' > ./template.txt

# run ad-hoc ansible command, passing any extra variables using -e
ansible localhost -m template -e somekey=abcd -a 'src=template.txt dest=output.txt'
# localhost | CHANGED => {
#     "changed": true,
#     "checksum": "c8bbd1e4edfb5124d7b77cf44dccc8b3743e8a40",
#     "dest": "./output.txt",
#     ...
# }

# check that the output rendered correctly
cat ./output.txt
# ["test", "template"] abcd
```

*But...it's pretty slow,* taking >600ms to evaluate a 1-line template even on a fast CPU.

---

You can do it much faster by calling the Ansible template Python API directly:

```
>>> from ansible.template import Templar

>>> Templar(loader=None).template('abc')
'abc'

>>> Templar(loader=None).template('{{"abc"|split("b")}}')
['a', 'c']

>>> Templar(loader=None, variables={'some_var': 1234}).template('{{some_var+1}}')
1235

# advanced: use loader plugins, inventory vars, etc.
>>> from ansible.plugins.loader import init_plugin_loader
>>> from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
>>> init_plugin_loader()
>>> Templar(loader=DataLoader()).template(...)
...
```

Here's the module source code, tests, and docs for Ansible `template`:

- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/template/__init__.py
- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/test/units/template/test_templar.py
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#template-module

More info about Ansible Python APIs including inventory variables, lookup plugins, and more:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#playbooks-variables
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#vars-and-facts